# Merge dataframes of list and obtain names of dataframes as column

Tags: r, list, rbind

I merged all data frames from a list in just one data frame.

The dataframes inside the list are called

```
TAI
NAM
HEE
```

and each data frame looks like this

```
Yr-M   Compound1 Compound 2
2015-01   0.002    0.15
2015-02   0.004    0.02
2015-03   0.01     0.09
```

when I merge all dataframes with `meanall<-do.call(rbind, meaneach)`  I get

```
         Yr-M  Compound1  Compound2
TAI.1   2015-01   0.002    0.15
TAI.2   2015-02   0.004    0.02
TAI.3   2015-03   0.01     0.09
  .
  .
  .
NAM.1   2015-01   0.03     0.4
NAM.2   2015-02   0.001    0.005
```

I would like to get a column with the names of the list and not as rownames (like above), and without the numbers (TAI.1, TAI.2...), I just want the name TAI

So that I get this:

```
 List    Yr-M  Compound1  Compound2
  TAI   2015-01   0.002    0.15
  TAI   2015-02   0.004    0.02
  TAI   2015-03   0.01     0.09
  .
  .
  .
  NAM   2015-01   0.03     0.4
  NAM   2015-02   0.001    0.005
```

How can I do this?

Comment: For a moment there I was trying to understand what the `mean` is doing inside `do.call`, but I guess you named your list as `mean`...? You can see why it is bad practice. As for rownames you can not have duplicates. So the best thing to do is convert the rownames to a column and then use `gsub` to remove the `.[0-9]`

Comment: I used a different name, but just changed it here to avoid misunderstandings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rownames you can not have duplicates. So the best thing to do is convert the rownames to a column and then use gsub to remove the .[0-9], i.e.

```
df <- do.call(rbind, your_list)
df$list_id <- gsub('\\..*', '', rownames(df))
```

Note that you can use `dplyr` or `data.table` version of rbinding a list which have the option of including the list names as a column, i.e.

```
dplyr::bind_rows(your_list, .id = 'list_id')
data.table::rbindlist(your_list, idcol = 'list_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional column with the listnames after merging the three lists via `do.call`:

```
nameColumn <- data.frame(listName = c(rep(c('TAI','NAM','HEE'),
                                          c(length(TAI),length(NAM),length(HEE) ))
meanall <- cbind(meanall, nameColumn)
```

If you want the `nameColumn` to be the first column, just switch arguments in `cbind` to

```
meanall <- cbind(nameColumn, meanall)
```